# How can I remove .NET and install an earlier version on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework

I am stuck with .net 4.8.03761 at registry
(528049)

I need to install .net 4.7.2 for my specific project but I can't because I can't remove the .net 4.8.

Any hints?

Comment: It is not possible to remove .NET Framework 4.8 from Windows 10 version 1903+ furthermore it’s not possible to install .NET Framework 4.7 on those versions.  **What your asking is not possible.** Your inability to run the application is not due to .NET Framework 4.8 being installed.  Your programming questions would need to be asked on Stack Overflow

Comment: "I need to install .net 4.7.2 for my specific project" - please elaborate on this need of yours. Myself (and the others in this thread) suspect you are mistaken in identifying your actual "need".

Comment: Sounds like OP needs to install the .net 4.7.2 SDK which can be installed side by side with the .net 4.8 runtime.

Comment: If your application works with .NET 4.7.2 but does not work in 4.8, that would indicate a breaking change in .NET framework. While not impossible, that's really a very rare circumstance. You should fix that in your application, because it will affect other users as well.

Comment: @ThomasWeller If it's actually a breaking change in the .NET framework, then I believe it falls to Microsoft, and not OP, to fix that.  I doubt this is the case.

Comment: @J...: what chances do you have? Wait 6 months until MS releases a new version that the customer will never install? I have always provided an immediate fix for my customers, not waiting on Microsoft.

Comment: @ThomasWeller We're talking about two different things, it seems.  It sounded like you were telling OP that they should fix the defect in the .NET framework.  That is not possible, obviously.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### I need to install .net 4.7.2 for my specific project but I can't remove the .net 4.8.

You shouldn't need to install anything if you have .net 4.8 installed as it will run applications written for 4.7.2:

> **.NET Framework 4.8**
>
> The .NET Framework 4.8 is included with:
>
> - [Windows 10 May 2019 Update](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4028685/windows-10-get-the-update)
>
> .NET Framework 4.8 can be used to run applications built for the .NET
> Framework 4.0 through 4.7.2.

Source: [Install the .NET Framework on Windows 10 | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-10)

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh We answer questions as asked. If the answers are wrong (because something in the question needs clarification) then it is up to the OP to let us know. In this case there are 2 different answers addressing two different aspects of the question. Again the OP is free to comment and choose, or better still clarify the question.

Answer (score 8):

> I am stuck with .net 4.8.03761

That is your runtime. It can run .NET applications for 4.5 and up to .NET 4.8. See .NET [Version compatibility](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility) for details. Support for .NET 2.0 through 3.5 <strike>and 4.0</strike> is separate.

> for my specific project

To develop for a .net target, you need an SDK for that particular target. You can have as many SKDs installed as you need.

The SDK and the runtime are not the same thing.

> I need to install .net 4.7.2

Download the [.NET 4.7.2 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net472-developer-pack-offline-installer). Not the runtime (you already have a newer compatible runtime).

See also [Is it possible to Install .net 4.7 version on my machine when .net 4.8 is already installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56864027/402022).

Comment: 4.0 isn't separate from 4.5. 4.5 is an in-place upgrade to 4.0. There are 4 basic CLR versions: 1.0, 1.1, 2.0 and 4.0. Anything from 4.x falls under 4.0 for compatibility purposes.